# Stop VBA from changing text to date when copy/paste

Tags: vba, date, text, copy, paste

I want to copy some texts from a sheet to another. For example: `01/02/2021` .
However VBA automatically convert it to `2020/01/02`. How can I stop it?
The following codes **didn't** work.

Example1:

```
sheet_1.Range("A1:A" & sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.End(xlDown).row).Copy
ws.Range("start").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
ws.Range("start").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Example2:

```
sheet_1.Range("A1:A" & sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.End(xlDown).row).Copy
    ws.Range("start").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
```

Example3:

```
sheet_1.Range("A1:A" & sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.End(xlDown).row).Copy
    ws.Range("start").Paste xlPaste Format:="Text" 'This causes an error
```

Comment: "some texts from a sheet to another. For example: 01/02/2021". It looks like Date, not text. If it were text, it would look like `'01/02/2021` (apostrophe before the first character in the formula string)

Comment: When I took a look at the original cell, its format is "General", not date.

Comment: VBA DOES NOT change text to date! What you see is Excel is "trying to be helpful" :) Work with cell formatting.

Comment: @АлексейР When I took a look at the original cell, its format is "General", not date. When I apply `Vartype` to that cell, it also shows 8.

Comment: @Gene Thanks for the comment. What I see is it DOES change text to dates. The original data is not formatted very well and 01/02/2021 is February 1st, not January 2nd. That is why I need to have it in string once and convert it into date manually.

Comment: When you put a string that Excel can interpret as a date into a cell--it will without fail. You might have a issue with US vs European date formatting.

Comment: Where from do you take that text looking like a date (for Excel)?

Comment: @FaneDuru An official website of Brazilian bank. The date is not in US format I suppose.

Comment: OK. How do you take it? What method do you use? I mean, it is important to 'convince' Excel that it is a string. And only after that to process it as you need.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am not sure if I am getting you correct but I downloaded the excel file from the website and put the entire sheet in the file that I am working on.

Comment: What kind of file do you download? Is it txt, csv or xls?

Comment: @FaneDuru It's xls.

Comment: Can you share such a sample file?

Comment: @FaneDuru http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/lum_web_v04_10_03_consulta.asp
You can download the file from the link in the upper area of the page.

Comment: "500 - Internal server error."...

Comment: Please, download such a file and share it using [this transfer site](https://easyupload.io/). It is free and easy to be used. But do it fast. In my country is late and I need to close my laptop...

Comment: @FaneDuru
 http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-de-segmentos-e-setoriais/serie-historica-do-di.htm Click on "PREQUISAR" then you can go to download page.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for the advice but I am not allowed to go to external site for downloading.

Comment: I tried opening it and Excel crushed...

Comment: @FaneDuru Hmm, it's a large data but shouldn't that much. It works on my end.

Comment: Please, try the code I pasted. It will extract the first column (where from the date starts - row 39) correctly formatted as date. This is possible because the downloaded file is not a real xls type. It is mostly txt file, opened as csv by Excel and trying to guess the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will extract the date from the (pseudo) xls file and place it in the first column of the active sheet. Correctly formatted as date:

```
Sub openXLSAsTextExtractDate()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, arrTXT, arrLine, arrD, arrDate, fileToOpen As String, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   fileToOpen = "xls file full name" 'use here the full name of the saved xls file
   'put the file content in an array splitting the read text by end of line (vbCrLf):
   arrTXT = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fileToOpen, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
   ReDim arrDate(UBound(arrTXT))          'redim the array where the date will be kept, to have enough space for all the date values
   For i = 39 To UBound(arrTXT) - 1       'iterate between the array elements, starting from the row where date data starts
        arrLine = Split(arrTXT(i), vbTab) 'split the line by vbTab
        arrD = Split(arrLine(0), "/")     'split the first line element (the date) by "/"
        arrDate(k) = DateSerial(arrD(2), arrD(1), arrD(0)): k = k + 1 'properely format as date and fill the arrDate elements
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arrDate(k - 1)         'keep only the array elements keeping data
    With sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrDate) + 1, 1)
        .value = Application.Transpose(arrDate)  'drop the array content
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"             'format the column where the date have been dropped
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

You did not say anything...

So, I made a code returning the whole table (in the active sheet). Please, test it. It will take only some seconds:

```
Sub openXLSAsText()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, arrTXT, arrLine, arrD, arrData, fileToOpen As String, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   fileToOpen =  "xls file full name" 'use here the full name of the saved xls file
   'put the file content in an array splitting the read text by end of line (vbCrLf):
   arrTXT = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fileToOpen, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)

   ReDim arrData(1 To 10, 1 To UBound(arrTXT))  'redim the array where the date will be kept, to have enough space for all the date values
   For i = 38 To UBound(arrTXT) - 1             'iterate between the array elements, starting from the row where table header starts
        arrLine = Split(arrTXT(i), vbTab)       'split the line by vbTab
        k = k + 1                               'increment the k variable (which will become the table row)
        For j = 0 To 9
            If j = 0 And k > 1 Then
                arrD = Split(arrLine(j), "/")   'split the first line element (the date) by "/"
                arrData(j + 1, k) = DateSerial(arrD(2), arrD(1), arrD(0)) 'propperely format as date and fill the arrDate elements
            ElseIf j = 2 Or j = 3 Then
                arrData(j + 1, k) = Replace(arrLine(j), ",", ".")  'correct the format for columns 3 and four (replace comma with dot)
            Else
                 arrData(j + 1, k) = arrLine(j)                    'put the rest of the column, not processed...
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To 10, 1 To k)      'keep only the array elements with data
    With sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrData, 2), UBound(arrData))
        .value = Application.Transpose(arrData)  'drop the array content
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit                    'autofit columns
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"  'format the first column
    End With
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```